# Redirecting URLs from /ch-de/ to /de/ and redirecting URLs with ? and &

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Internet research didn't help me so I am desperately to ask the community for an answer. The problem is:
we have transferred a webshop from Joomla-Virtuemart to PrestaShop. Now we have a problem with redirecting URLs.

For example, the following syntax in .htaccess doesn't work:

> Redirect
>   301   http://wedding-shop.com/ch-de/Brautschmuck/Schmuckset-Miranda   http://wedding-shop.com/de/brautschmuck/61-schmuckset-miranda-braut.html

What it does, is replacing the `/ch-de/` in initial URL to `/de/` and shows the non-existing page which raises 404 error.

After talking to my hoster, which helped me preparing .htaccess file, he told me, that there should be some logic in PrestaShop for that. I am desperately trying to find this out, but resultless.

Another problem are the type of URLs

> .../ch-de/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=2484&category_id=90&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=1

which doesn't work in .htaccess file. Here, I have no idea why. I have about 700 of this type of URLs.

Would appreciate any hints to solve this problem...
Thanks in advance,
Lionna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match URL's `http://` part in `Redirect` directive. Use this instead:

```
Redirect 301 /ch-de/Brautschmuck/Schmuckset-Miranda http://wedding-shop.com/de/brautschmuck/61-schmuckset-miranda-braut.html
```

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file and what is the URL you tried?

Comment: Provide your full .htaccess in your question and also clarify your requirements. Clearly it won't work for `/ch-de/index.php?page=shop` URLs.

Comment: the requirement is to make this Redirect 301 /ch-de/Brautschmuck/Schmuckset-Miranda http://wedding-shop.com/de/brautschmuck/61-schmuckset-miranda-braut.html work

Comment: My answer is perfectly working fine. Make sure this is **very first rule** in your .htaccess.

Comment: well, unfortunately it does not... I have added the code of .htaccess above the urls list. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I just noticed your .htaccess. My suggested rule should be **very first rule** but it doesn't appear there.

Comment: it does.. the last line is the same as you have suggested. Or what do you mean by saying the very first rule? Where to I have to place what?

Comment: Not last line, move that line to the top and make it first line in .htaccess file.

Comment: Amazingly it works for /ch-de/ links, when I put them at the very top of .htaccess file, thank you so much! Do you know how can I solve the second problem of this kind of links:     /ch-de/Perlenkette-mit-Band/index.php?page=shop.browse&category_id=69&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=1

Comment: If it worked for this it's better to accept this question and create a new for other problem. Which I could answer also using mod rewrite but I am on movie now and cannot type code without computer.

Comment: Got it, posted a new question. Unfortunately, cannot vote for your answer, as I don't have enough reputation, but accepted as best. Thanks a lot again!!!

Comment: Thanks I will try to answer your new question also if un-answered.

Answer (score 0):

Grüezi Lionna,

Try out this code:

```
RedirectMatch ^/ch-de/(.*)$ http://wedding-shop.com/de/$1
```

Comment: Grüeziwohl Adam ;) I added this code here: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wedding-shop.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
RedirectMatch ^/ch-de/(.*)$ http://wedding-shop.com/de/$1 , cleared cache, but it didn't help..